# IIS Doesn't work outside local network

Tags: iis, firewall, domain, port

I have set up a website on IIS 7.0. Does anyone know why I would not be able to access the site outside of my local network?  I have pointed a .com address to my ip address and it works fine on the host computer.  However, I can't get it to work on any outside computers.

Comment: Firewall rules? NAT? Port forwarding?

Comment: what say `nsloookup yousite.com` and `nslookup you_ip`? nslookup gives the correct correspondence? Can you `ping` you host by name and by ip-address? You must check it from outside of your local network.

Comment: Are you using an internal IP address instead of the external IP?

Comment: When you are testing going to the public name are you inside the network or outside?  Some routers won't let you be inside and access the public IP.  You may need to go to Starbucks or something to test the public name and IP.

Comment: Is 192.168.1.3 an internal ip address? That's what I am using.

Comment: Yes, 192.168.* is a private IP range, which routers on the Internet are configured to drop. Likewise 172.16-32.*, 169.254.*, and 10.* .

Comment: Well my ipconfig only has addresses that start with 192.168.  When I go to whatismyip.com it gives me the ip of my internet service provider.  How can I find the ip of my local machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be a series of things as listed in the comments. For starters I would look at the IP address. Make sure you are using your networks external IP address instead of the Internal IP address. Then you would need to access the website on a connection that is outside the network to see you are successful. Also look into redirect rules. If you created the website as **www.domainname.com**, and you are typing **domainname.com** in your URL address box, then it will not redirect to **www.domainname.com**. A redirect is required in order to use just the route of the address within the URL. Lastly, you would need to look at the firewall rules. Check to see if the port you are setting the website up on is allowed through the firewall.

Comment: I think I may be using an internal ip address. I will be able to check in about an hour. I will mark the question correct if this does work.